# XSLT: organize html tables for print

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on an xslt which takes a list of items from xml, and makes an html table for each.

The problem is when I try to print the document.. the tables on the end on the page are broken to the next page.
I need the tables to appear fully on a page, and their height may change.

I've tried to insert a div with the css page-break-after: always; and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This isn't really an XSLT question at all, it's an HTML/CSS question. If you know what HTML/CSS you want to generate, then writing the XSLT is probably easy. Until you know what HTML/CSS you want to generate, you shouldn't even start writing XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

just to add the css rule for the table

```
table{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```